# Better way of coding this if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have another question for you very helpful people. I use a lot of if statements many of which are just repeated and I'm sure could be shortened. This is my current bit of code

```
if (Globals.TotalStands <= 1)
{
    ScoreUpdate.StandNo2.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreStand2.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreOutOf2.Visible = false;
}

if (Globals.TotalStands <= 2)
{
    ScoreUpdate.StandNo3.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreStand3.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreOutOf3.Visible = false;
}

if (Globals.TotalStands <= 3)
{
    ScoreUpdate.StandNo4.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreStand4.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreOutOf4.Visible = false;
}

if (Globals.TotalStands <= 4)
{
    ScoreUpdate.StandNo5.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreStand5.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreOutOf5.Visible = false;
}

if (Globals.TotalStands <= 5)
{
    ScoreUpdate.StandNo6.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreStand6.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreOutOf6.Visible = false;
}

if (Globals.TotalStands <= 6)
{
    ScoreUpdate.StandNo7.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreStand7.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreOutOf7.Visible = false;
}

if (Globals.TotalStands <= 7)
{
    ScoreUpdate.StandNo8.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreStand8.Visible = false;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreOutOf8.Visible = false;
}
```

as you can see there is a huge amount of code to do something simple (which I do on a few other forms as well and I'm sure there must be a better way of coding this that gets the same result? I'm a code noob so please be gentle, code is C# and software is Visual studio 2008 pro.

Comment: Sorry but which language are you using? This could be one of several.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of your properties should be arrays (or some other collection). For example:

```
ScoreUpdate.StandNo6
```

could be this instead:

```
ScoreUpdate.StandNos[5]
```

Then you can use a loop instead of all those `if` statements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Globals.TotalStands; ++i)
{
    ScoreUpdate.StandNos[i].Visible = true;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreStands[i].Visible = true;
    ScoreUpdate.ScoreOutOfs[i].Visible = true;
}
```

Or this slight variation might be better where there is an array of ScoreUpdates rather than three separate arrays:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Globals.TotalStands; ++i)
{
    var scoreUpdate = ScoreUpdates[i];
    scoreUpdate.StandNo.Visible = true;
    scoreUpdate.ScoreStand.Visible = true;
    scoreUpdate.ScoreOutOf.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: how do i go about changing my properties to arrays. e.g. ScoreUpdate.StandNo6 is a label on another form? Thansk again

Comment: HadlowJ: To change them you'd have to add the controls to your form dynamically rather than doing it in the designer. But you don't actually *need* to change anything, you can also just add an array containing references to your existing controls. You can populate it in the constructor by doing a bunch of assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You should make three arrays or lists of controls and use a loop.